# Configure apache2 virtual host subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, virtualhost

I have configured apache2 virtual host with a sub domain in the following way:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/website:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName website.local
  ServerAlias sub.website.local
  DocumentRoot /home/myname/dev/website/web/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 website.local
127.0.0.1 sub.website.local
```

And it works! Both `http://website.local` and `http://sub.websitel.local` point to DocumentRoot. Now, how do I reconfigure this, so that any subdomain `http://*.website.local` will point to DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a wildcard to match any subdomain name in apache:

```
serveralias *.website.local
```

the problem is the hosts file doesn't support wildcards. if you use a local dns bind service as a resolver you can register the website.local zone and create the dns wildcard as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. For instructions on setting up DNS for this look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/188796/localhost-subdomains-with-bind9

Answer (score 2):

In apache.conf:

ServerAlias *.website.local

However it is not possible to use wildcards in /etc/hosts.
You would need to setup a DNS server for that.