# Localhost subdomains with Bind9

Tags: subdomain, localhost, bind

So, following this question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/188647/configure-apache2-virtual-host-subdomain) and a number of other questions about subdomains on localhost, we learned that /etc/hosts isn't capable of handling wildcard routes and we need a DNS system. Ok, I have installed Bind9 on my machine (Ubuntu). Now, could someone finally explain how to set it up to route *.domain.local to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following A record to your "local" zone:

```
*.domain.local. IN A 127.0.0.1
```

Don't forget to configure your machine to use that DNS server (in /etc/resolv.conf).

Comment: And if it's the only zone you're hosting don't forget to set at least one forwarder.

Comment: Thank you guys, that worked out for me. However I also had to add a  zone "domain.local" to /etc/bind/named.conf (same as "localhost").